# How to GET a string from a URL without omitting spaces in JAVA

Tags: java, whitespace, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader

I have a simple program that sends a GET request and fetches a string.
The URL is a PHP page I wrote that fetches some data from a database on the server and parses it into a string with a bunch of white-space characters (which I need).
The problem is the spaces get omitted in the response to the java app, and my question is how to avoid omitting them?

**My java code:**

```
URL servicesUrlObj = new URL("https://myurl.mysite.com/placeholder.php");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) servicesUrlObj.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + servicesUrlObj);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    content.append(inputLine);
}
reader.close();

System.out.println(content.toString());
```

original string:

`200329951      123      3  03/09/18`

the string that gets returned from the request:

`200329951123303/09/18`

Comment: Are you sure it's a Java problem? What you get when you do the request from a web browser?

Comment: Just a question: Is there any reason why you don't access the Database in your Java code directly? Is the original string getting prompted if you access your PHP script within any browser?

Comment: Can you confirm that the values are send on 1 line only, and that they are not sended with newline instead of spaces (meaning that you are just appending the result badly) ? We need to see how the data is send originally (include a PHP snippet please).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Manu Rivas's comment, i found the problem. I wasn't appending the spaces to the output parameter in my php file correctly.
I did:

```
$spaces . ' ';
```

instead of:

```
$spaces = $spaces . ' ';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very elegant solution, but you could consider adding a `content.append(" ")` to your while loop, or even just turning your current line into `content.append(inputLine + " ");`

Comment: I would propose `content.append(inputLine).append(" ")` to be coherent. Using a `StringBuffer` but still doing `String` concatenation in the method doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Not sure why you'd add spaces when the loop is reading lines. Since there's only one line in the question, this doesn't answer it anyway